# Grid search and KerasClassifier using class weights

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, grid-search

I am trying to conduct grid search using [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/0.18/auto_examples/model_selection/randomized_search.html) `RandomizedSearchCV` function together with [Keras](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/) `KerasClassifier` wrapper for my unbalanced multi-class classification problem. However, when I try to give `class_weight` as an input, the fit method gives me the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot clone object <keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier object at 0x000002AA3C676710>, as the constructor either does not set or modifies parameter class_weight
```

Below are the functions that I use to build the `KerasClassifier` and the script for `RandomizedSearchCV`:

build_fn:

```
import keras as k

def build_keras_model(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'], optimiser = 'adam', 
                  learning_rate = 0.001, n_neurons = 30, n_layers = 1, n_classes = 3,
                  l1_reg = 0.001, l2_reg = 0.001, batch_norm = False, dropout = None, 
                  input_shape = (8,)):

model = k.models.Sequential()

model.add(k.layers.Dense(n_neurons, 
                         input_shape = input_shape,
                         kernel_regularizer = k.regularizers.l1_l2(l1 = l1_reg, l2 = l2_reg),
                         activation = 'relu'))
if batch_norm is True:
    model.add(k.layers.BatchNormalization())
if dropout is not None:
    model.add(k.layers.Dropout(dropout))

i = 1   
while i < n_layers:
    model.add(k.layers.Dense(n_neurons,
                             kernel_regularizer = k.regularizers.l1_l2(l1 = l1_reg, l2 = l2_reg),
                             activation = 'relu'))
    if batch_norm is True:
        model.add(k.layers.BatchNormalization())
    if dropout is not None:
        model.add(k.layers.Dropout(dropout))
    i += 1
del i

model.add(k.layers.Dense(n_classes, activation = 'softmax'))

if optimiser == 'adam':
    koptimiser = k.optimizers.Adam(lr = learning_rate)
elif optimiser == 'adamax':
    koptimiser = k.optimizers.Adamax(lr = learning_rate)
elif optimiser == 'nadam':
    koptimiser = k.optimizers.Nadam(lr = learning_rate)
else:
    print('Unknown optimiser type')

model.compile(optimizer = koptimiser, loss = loss, metrics = metrics)

model.summary()

return model
```

Script:

```
import scipy as sp
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

parameters =    {
            'optimiser': ['adam', 'adamax', 'nadam'],
            'learning_rate': sp.stats.uniform(0.0005, 0.0015),
            'epochs': sp.stats.randint(500, 1501),
            'n_neurons': sp.stats.randint(20, 61),
            'n_layers': sp.stats.randint(1, 3),
            'n_classes': [3],
            'batch_size': sp.stats.randint(1, 11),
            'l1_reg': sp.stats.reciprocal(1e-3, 1e1),
            'l2_reg': sp.stats.reciprocal(1e-3, 1e1),
            'batch_norm': [False],
            'dropout': [None],
            'metrics': [['accuracy']],
            'loss': ['sparse_categorical_crossentropy'],
            'input_shape': [(training_features.shape[1],)]
            }

class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(training_targets), 
                                     training_targets[target_label[0]])
class_weights = dict(enumerate(class_weights))

keras_model = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_keras_model, verbose = 0, class_weight = class_weights)

clf = RandomizedSearchCV(keras_model, parameters, n_iter = 1, scoring = 'f1_micro', 
                         n_jobs = 1, cv = 5, random_state = random_state)


clf.fit(training_features, training_targets.values[:, 0])

model = clf.best_estimator_
```

Comment: Ahh have you tried to pass class_weights in the fit method:
`grid_result = clf.fit(training_features, training_targets.values[:, 0], clf__class_weight=class_weights)`

Comment: When I tried to do this, I got the following error:

`TypeError: Unrecognized keyword arguments: {'clf__class_weight': {0: 1.76, 1: 0.6285714285714286, 2: 1.1891891891891893}}`

Comment: and without the clf__ prefix?

Comment: Yes, I tried now and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: OK, I will post it as an answer, just to complete the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass class_weights in this scenario with `KerasClassifier`, the class_weights should be passed in the fit method and then will be forwarded to the keras model.

```
grid_result = clf.fit(training_features, training_targets.values[:, 0], class_weight=class_weights)
```

In older versions it was neccecary to pass them with the clf__ prefix:

```
grid_result = clf.fit(training_features, training_targets.values[:, 0], clf__class_weight=class_weights)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a **KerasClassifier**, to use class weights, even for **GridSearch**, use **fit_params** functionality to add multiple parameters as the build_fn calls the model function and does not accept arguments.

`

```
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn = build_classifier, epochs=20, batch_size = 128)
    
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator=classifier, X = X_train, y = y_train, cv = 3, 
                             n_jobs = -1, verbose=0, 
                             fit_params = {'callbacks': [EarlyStopping()],
                             class_weight:class_weights})
```

`